# Dropdown menu isn't searchable with images as labels

Tags: python, plotly, dropdown, plotly-dash

Adding images to dropdown labels as described in paragraph *Components as Option Labels* in
https://dash.plotly.com/dash-core-components/dropdown
makes labels not searchable even though *searchable=True* is set.

Is there workaround to make labels searchable as usual?

Minimal working code:

```
import pandas as pd     
import plotly            
import plotly.express as px
import json

import dash_bootstrap_components as dbc
import dash             
import dash_core_components as dcc
import dash_html_components as html
from dash.dependencies import Input, Output


df = pd.read_csv('data_bdo.csv', index_col=0)

temp=[
        {
            "label": html.Div(
                [
                    html.Img(src="/assets/1.png", height=20),
                    html.Div("Python", style={'font-size': 15, 'padding-left': 10}),
                ], style={'display': 'flex', 'align-items': 'center', 'justify-content': 'center'}
            ),
            "value": "Python",
        },
        {
            "label": html.Div(
                [
                    html.Img(src="/assets/2.png", height=20),
                    html.Div("Julia", style={'font-size': 15, 'padding-left': 10}),
                ], style={'display': 'flex', 'align-items': 'center', 'justify-content': 'center'}
            ),
            "value": "Julia",
        },]
    
    
app = dash.Dash(__name__, external_stylesheets=[dbc.themes.DARKLY],update_title = None )

app.layout = html.Div([

    html.Div([
        dcc.Dropdown(id='my_dropdown',
            options=temp,
            searchable=True                    #allow user-searching of dropdown values
            )],className='three columns')])

@app.callback(
    Output(component_id='the_graph', component_property='figure'),
    [Input(component_id='my_dropdown', component_property='value')]
)

def update_bar_chart(my_dropdown):
    df = pd.read_csv('data_bdo.csv', index_col=0)
    fig = px.bar(df[["name", my_dropdown]].dropna().sort_values(by=my_dropdown,ascending=False), 
                     x="name", 
                     y=my_dropdown, 
                     template = 'plotly_dark',
                     text=my_dropdown,
                     labels={my_dropdown:"Amount of "+ str(my_dropdown)}
                     )
    fig.update_traces(textfont_size=13, textposition="outside", cliponaxis=False)
    return fig

if __name__ == '__main__':
    app.run_server(debug=True, use_reloader=False)
```

Dropdown with options of the form [{'label': 'Python', 'value': 'Python'}] is searchable though...

Comment: better show minimal working code

Comment: @furas added code, but I fear it's not minimal, although you should get the idea. Dropdowns with labels as html.Div aren't searchable.

Comment: when I run this code then it shows error in browser - it has to be `value` instead of `my_dropdown` in `def update_bar_chart(value):` - and the same inside this function.

Comment: and it has problem because there is no object `the_graph` in HTML - so this code is minimal but NOT working.

Comment: I think this can search only pure text in `label`, not in `value`, but when you add image then label has HTML. OR it searchs maching text at the beginning of label but when label has image then at the beginning it has HTML with `image`. It would need to rewrite JavaScript code for searching with image.

Comment: Yes that's what I was thinking aswell. Sad that plotly implemented it that way. I have to choose to either have a search function or images :(
Thank you for looking up into this! 
I have 0 knowledge in JavaScript, thought there would be simple workaround. @furas